# Why does Python raise a KeyboardInterrupt exception when the user hits Enter in input()?

Tags: python, ios

I'm fairly new to Python.  I've just started working with PythonforIOS 3.4, and am having trouble with input().  I think it's a bug in the IOS implementation but want to be sure I understand things correctly.

If the user just hits enter (a null response) a KeyboardInterrupt exception is raised instead of simply returning a null string ('') as the result which is what I had expected.
Is this correct?  In Python 2 raw_input does return '' I think.  I had understood that in Python 3 input replaced raw_input.

Comment: Sample code to reproduce the alleged bug?

Comment: Next time please describe the actual question or problem in the title. If the title just mentions that it's a "qu (sic) about Python input()", or that it's "beginner", it's really vague and hard to find. And it does not matter if you're a beginner or not. If the question is good and interesting, your level of expertise really is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Try some testing:

```
try:
    s = input('enter string: ')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Error raised'
```

If the 'Error raised' message prints up, which I'm sure it will from what your question says, then it is likely a bug in iOS. From what I know, the `input` function in Python 3 can take an empty string, though I'm not for sure as I don't yet work in Python 3.

I would suggest for now, putting a try/except case in a while loop to prevent blank input from occurring like:

```
while True:
    try:
        s = input('enter string: ')
        break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        continue
```

And report the bug to Apple. As for "I had understood that in Python 3 input replaced raw_input", you are correct there, `input()` is the only standard way to get user input.

Also, the only way that people can help you fully is if you post your code that you are having problems with.

Comment: Yes I had figured out the except clause which is how I was sure what was happening.   Thank you for confirming that input should accept a null string, I will raise this with the implementer.  I didn't post the code as it was simply     z = input('> ')   - before I added the try/except wrapper.

Comment: Got ya. Well good luck @RFlack

Comment: 3.4 is still on testing, and Python is new to iOS. I think this is not suprising.